# How to make XTerm smaller-vt-font() and larger-vt-font() use smoother steps?

Tags: fonts, xterm

I'm using `smaller-vt-font()` and `larger-vt-font()` to quickly change the font size. However, the steps in which the font size changes are too big and I want them to be smoother so the resulting font sizes are closer to the default font size.

After doing some research, I think I have to redefine the "Unreadable", "Tiny", "Small", "Medium", "Large" and "Huge" font sizes. There is [this particular question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332316/configure-unreadable-tiny-small-huge-xterm-fonts) which describes the issue. However, `terminus-12`, `terminus-14` and so on won't work, because `xlsfonts` doesn't list those bitmap font aliases for me:

```
$ xlsfonts
-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--0-0-75-75-c-0-iso8859-1
-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-100-100-100-c-60-iso8859-1
-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1
6x13
cursor
fixed
```

Currently, my `.Xresources` looks like this:

```
XTerm*faceName: DejaVu Sans Mono
XTerm*faceSize: 12
XTerm.vt100.translations: #override \n\
  Ctrl <Key> minus: smaller-vt-font() \n\
  Ctrl <Key> plus: larger-vt-font()
```

What do I need to add, to set the sizes of "Unreadable", "Tiny", "Small", "Medium", "Large" and "Huge" to 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, and 14 for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's done with the related ***`faceSize1`***, etc., resources mentioned in the [xterm manual page](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:faceSize).

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a specific example to Thomas Dickeys [great answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/510837/515876): I added the following lines to .Xresources:

```
 XTerm.vt100.faceSize1: 9
 XTerm.vt100.faceSize2: 10
 XTerm.vt100.faceSize3: 11
 XTerm.vt100.faceSize4: 12
 XTerm.vt100.faceSize5: 13
 XTerm.vt100.faceSize6: 14
 XTerm.vt100.faceSize7: 15
```

And then did the usual procedure to have XTerm pick up the configuration change (`xrdb ~/.XResources` and restarting XTerm).