# Changing xterm font size without a mouse

Tags: xterm

It's possible to change the `xterm` font size by holding `ctrl` and right-clicking the window.  Is it possible to do it without a mouse?

Comment: Related and possibly a duplicate: [How to make XTerm smaller-vt-font() and larger-vt-font() use smoother steps?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510829/how-to-make-xterm-smaller-vt-font-and-larger-vt-font-use-smoother-steps).
See the ```XTerm.vt100.translations: #override  \n\```.

Comment: That's related, but not a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [default keybindings](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Default-Key-Bindings) include what's needed:

```
           Shift~Ctrl <KeyPress> KP_Add:larger-vt-font() \n\
           Shift Ctrl <KeyPress> KP_Add:smaller-vt-font() \n\
           Shift <KeyPress> KP_Subtract:smaller-vt-font() \n\
```

That is (without any customization needed):

- <kbd>*shift*</kbd><kbd>`keypad +`</kbd> switches to the next-larger font.
- <kbd>*shift*</kbd><kbd>`keypad -`</kbd> switches to the next-smaller font.

There are two bindings for `KP_Add` to make it workable by default on some unusual keyboards.

This was originally just for bitmap-fonts (in [1999](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_92)); TrueType fonts were accommodated in [2008](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_237).

It is also possible to do this with an [escape-sequence](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Operating-System-Commands:OSC-Ps;Pt-ST:Ps-=-5-0.1019), e.g.,

```
printf '\033]50;#+1\007'
```

to switch to the next-larger font, and

```
printf '\033]50;#-1\007'
```

to switch to the next-smaller font.  The [`fonts.sh`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/master/vttests/fonts.sh) script in the sources makes xterm repeatedly shrink/grow, and when interrupted, restores the original font.  (The `\007` in the `printf` is a nonprinting control/G in the script to accommodate very old shells).

Comment: Thank you.  Would you explain how to do it with an escape sequence as well?  I couldn't tell from the linked page.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
xterm -fa 'Monospace' -fs 14
```