# How to set XTerm unicode Font?

Tags: xterm, x-resources

Can I have an additional font in my .Xresources so that if the default one doesn't have some unicode characters, the additional one can display them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are seven font sizes, as can be seen with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MouseRightButton</kbd> on XTerm. [They can
be set in .Xresources](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/332316).

- `font` = Default
- `font1` = Unreadable
- `font2` = Tiny
  ...
- `font6` = Huge

So you can set a default `font` that misses some unicode characters. If you miss them, change to a font that supports them, for example, Tiny. This `.Xresources` file does it:

```
XTerm*font:  -*-courier 10 pitch-medium-r-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-ascii-*
XTerm*font2: -*-fixed-medium-r-*-*-15-*-*-*-*-*-iso10646-*
```

Answer (score 1):

xterm has two sets of bitmap-fonts:

- [font](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:font), [font2](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:font2), font3, ..., font6 are the conventional fonts dating back to X11R4.
- [utf8Fonts](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:utf8Fonts).font, etc., are Unicode fonts.

The app-defaults files [XTerm](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/d3bd1249f36040570d702aa0d030261ed79103cf/XTerm.ad#L143) and [UXTerm](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/d3bd1249f36040570d702aa0d030261ed79103cf/UXTerm.ad#L63) have both of these, but in the latter, those Unicode fonts are not inside the [utf8Fonts](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:utf8Fonts) layer.  Here is the content from the `XTerm` app-defaults file:

```
*VT100.utf8Fonts.font2: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--8-80-75-75-c-50-iso10646-1
*VT100.utf8Fonts.font:  -misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1
*VT100.utf8Fonts.font3: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--14-130-75-75-c-70-iso10646-1
*VT100.utf8Fonts.font4: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-c-80-iso10646-1
*VT100.utf8Fonts.font5: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--18-120-100-100-c-90-iso10646-1
*VT100.utf8Fonts.font6: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--20-200-75-75-c-100-iso10646-1
```

and here is the content from the `UXTerm` app-defaults file:

```
*VT100.font2:   -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--8-80-75-75-c-50-iso10646-1
*VT100.font:    -misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1
*VT100.font3:   -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--14-130-75-75-c-70-iso10646-1
*VT100.font4:   -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-c-80-iso10646-1
*VT100.font5:   -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--18-120-100-100-c-90-iso10646-1
*VT100.font6:   -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--20-200-75-75-c-100-iso10646-1
```

Just reading the [XTerm](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/d3bd1249f36040570d702aa0d030261ed79103cf/XTerm.ad#L111) app-defaults file, most users would not notice that the non-UTF-8 fonts given here look **something** like the UTF-8 fonts:

```
*VT100.font1:       nil2
*IconFont:      nil2
*fontMenu*font2*Label:  Tiny
*VT100.font2:       5x7
*fontMenu*font3*Label:  Small
*VT100.font3:       6x10
*fontMenu*font4*Label:  Medium
*VT100.font4:       7x13
*fontMenu*font5*Label:  Large
*VT100.font5:       9x15
*fontMenu*font6*Label:  Huge
*VT100.font6:       10x20
```

Those short names are (as detailed in [*xterm cannot load font*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59593455/xterm-cannot-load-font/59601865#59601865)) aliases for ISO-8859-1 fonts, which (unsuprisingly given the history of UTF-8) have the same appearance as the UTF-8 fonts.  But they have only 192 characters (256 - 64 control characters), while the bitmap UTF-8 fonts have thousands.

There is more than one app-defaults file because that seemed a simpler solution than the **`utf8Fonts`** arrangement.  The [uxterm](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/master/uxterm) script selects the latter at startup using the [**-class**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-class) option, but as described in the manual page, xterm will automatically select the utf8Fonts at startup based on the locale settings.

xterm has menu items for [UTF-8 Encoding](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT-Fonts:UTF-8-Encoding) and [UTF-8 Fonts](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT-Fonts:UTF-8-Fonts).  If your locale uses UTF-8 encoding (and if the [`locale`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:locale) resource uses the default value), then xterm pre-selects these menu items and disables them from being changed.  If the locale does not use UTF-8 encoding, you are able to change these menu entries and see the resulting differences.

You can specify in your X resources which file to use by prefixing the resources with **`XTerm`** or **`UXTerm`**, respectively.

While one could make *font sets* using bitmap fonts, which would allow one to do what's asked in the question:

> Can I have an additional font in my .Xresources so that if the default one doesn't have some unicode characters, the additional one can display them?

xterm uses only one of these bitmap-fonts at a time (along with automatically using bold- and italic-versions).  There is a font-set feature in the X libraries, but it has severe performance problems and was never widely used.  In xterm, it is treated as a nuisance (see [menuLocale](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#slow_menus) resource).

Besides bitmap-fonts, xterm also supports TrueType fonts, and will automatically lookup fonts as needed to fill in for missing glyphs from the family specified with the [`-fa`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-fa) option.  Depending on your fontconfig arrangement, you can get a workable coverage from the TrueType fonts (with the caveat that some of those are sized incorrectly).

Comment: When I run ```uxterm -class 'XTerm' ```, it launches a terminal with a really ugly font but which displays Unicode correctly.

Comment: sure - read the answer and the linked X resource-settings.  (The "really ugly font" here isn't one of the many TrueType fonts which merit that description, but a bitmap font).